# Symfony 4 how to use my own Bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I have my own Admin Bundle which is being developed in time. I just put it into new project and use it. If I need a new functionality I add it and use it later in another project. I put it in `src/` directory. I don't want to store in on public Git repository.

Now as Symfony 4 is bundle-less, how should I easly put it into `src/` dir so that it is decoupled from other App code?

I would like to develop the App as I shoulg but I would like to have an opportunity to easly copy Admin code to use it for another project.

Comment: As I understood it, Symfony 4 will use recipes to manage bundles, check [this](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/README.rst#configurators)

Comment: If you have a bundle, it won't stop you. If you want to put all the views into a top-level directory, and move the classes/services/entities/etc you can. Or, just use the bundle as you currently are.

Comment: @Hollyol Recipes are used to install, configure bundles. What I mean in my question is how to handle my own 'not vendor based' bundle.

Comment: @AlisterBulman I will put my top level classess, services into src and tempaltes into tempaltes. But I want to have the Admin part, my own bundle, decouple so it is easy to reuse. So I think I should put my app into src/App and my Admin Bundle into src/Admin, right?

Comment: Symfony 4 still uses bundles.  It's only the AppBundle which is going away.  So make yourself a src/AdminBundle and do things just as you would for S2/3.

Comment: I think this symfony doc may help you : https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-4-a-new-way-to-develop-applications

Comment: Ok, thank you. @Cerad or AllisterBulman can you post the answer? I want to mark it. dom thank you, I have read the docs and didn't catch this idea clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundles are still perfectly available and useful in Symfony 4. They aren't suggested to be used for the main program code, as it is a little easier to not need that structure.

3rd party bundles are still incredibly useful though, to easily connect functionality, templates and services to an application.  Equally, if you have some code that can be used in multiple applications and most easily added as a bundle, you are perfectly able to write your code as its own bundle. You can initially write it within your src/ directory, and then migrate it out to be an external bundle/library that can be pulled in via Composer when it's useful to do so.